# Play Video from button

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, iframe, youtube

I'm creating a little plugin to control a Youtube Video with custom controls.

```
var player = new YT.Player('ytPlayer', {
    height : 400,
    width : 500,
    videoId : 'U0Og4LaB1Zc',
    events: {
        'onReady' : onYoutubePlayerStateChange,
        'onStateChange' : onYoutubePlayerStateChange
    }
});
```

**I want to have a button:**

```
<button type="button"> onclick="document.getElementById('ytPlayer').playVideo()">PLAY</button>
```

**Although I get the error.**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLIFrameElement> has no method 'playVideo'
```

I **DONT** want to use the variable player to play the video, as the plugin can create multiple video instances, but I **DO** know the **ID** of the iframe I would like to take control of.

So to summarize, I want to have my own buttons to control an iframe of my choosing without using the variable player as it's not global. Nor do I want it to be :)